# activedocument' is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level(VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I am using visual studio(vb.net)during internship.It is a new language for me.I had stuck in this question few day.Can anyone help me to solve error.Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing

Public Class Form1
    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Create a word file
        Using wordDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create("C:\Users\ericc\Desktop\vb testing purpose\test.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
            ' Add a main document part. 
            Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()
        ' Create the document structure and add some text.
            mainPart.Document = New Document()
            Dim body As Body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
            Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
            Dim run As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())
            run.AppendChild(New Text(""))
        End Using
        Dim strDoc As String = "C:\Users\ericc\Desktop\vb testing purpose\test.docx"
        GetSetDocVars(strDoc)
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetSetDocVars(ByVal strDoc As String)
        Dim fName As String
        fName = "Jeff Smith"
        ' Set contents of variable "fName" in a document using a document
        ' variable called "FullName".
        ActiveDocument.Variables.Add(Name:="FullName", Value:=fName)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the error:'ActiveDocument' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: You're mixing vba and .Net WinForms. You have to pick one or the other.

Comment: Ok.So Public Sub Form1_Load is .Net WinForms part and Public Sub GetSetDocVars is vba part,am i right?

Comment: I think you need to use something like `Dim word As Word.Application` and initialize it first, then use `word.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add(...)` (the message clearly indicates `ActiveDocument` is not declared before use).

Comment: I suspect you're trying to mix DocumentFormat.OpenXml code with Word interop code. Your sub `GetSetDocVars` seems to be from the word interop library, while the rest is from `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` I don't know anything useful about openxml, but [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4b9e1395-292e-495c-ae90-d43541a3a54b/adding-andor-changing-document-variables-in-word-document-using-open-xml?forum=oxmlsdk) might help